# Which choice is equal to $\log_{a}(\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{b}})$ for all a,b>0?

Tags: logarithms

I don't understand how can I reach the correct alternative ("None of the above is valid for all a,b>0), is there anybody whose understood could explain me?

(a) $\frac{1}{2}[\ln(3)-\log_a(b)]$

(b) $\sqrt{\ln(3)-\log_a(b)}$

(c) $\frac{1}{2}[3-\frac{1}{\log_b(a)}]$

(d) $\sqrt{3+\log_b(a)}$

(e) None of the above is valid for all a,b>0.

I've reached the alternative (c) :

$\log_a(\sqrt{a^3})-\log_a(\sqrt{b})=\log_a(a^{\frac{3}{2}})-\log_a(b^{\frac{1}{2}})=\frac{1}{2}(3-\log_a(b))=\frac{1}{2}(3-\frac{1}{\log_b(a)})$

Comment: (c) is almost correct, but the absolute value is wrong.

Comment: @blamocur I see braces, not absolute value?

Comment: "For all $a,b>0$", so (c) would be undefined when $b=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot to consider this case

Comment: (c) is the right one.

Comment: @DavidRaveh: you are right, I am wrong :(